# PHP output buffer

Tags: php7

Tengo el siguiente código que sirve para crear un nuevo / modificar un presupuesto.
El formulario para nuevo presupuesto y modificar un presupuesto es el mismo.
La diferencia está en que para modificar un presupuesto el formulario debe estar "precargado".
Para reutilizar el formulario y el procesamiento del formulario,
puse en un archivo el procesamiento del formulario (`presupuesto_procesar.php`) separando las acciones
conforme a si es un nuevo presupuesto o una actualización. Ese archivo proxy funciona correctamente.
El archivo `presupuestos_formulario.php` que es el formulario común para altas/modificaciones contiene código PHP para
autocompletarlo por lo que debo usar output buffering. Cunado uso output buffering, el formulario se muestra correctamente
conforme a los modificaciones del usuario. Pero no se muestran los mensajes de error (`$hay_errores`). Que si se muestran
cuando el formulario está 'pegado' (o sea, que no uso el buffer).

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once("inc/config.php");

$titulo_pagina = "Presupuesto nuevo";

require_once("presupuesto_procesar.php");

include("inc/html_head.php");
include("inc/html_menu.php");

?>
    <h1><?=$titulo_pagina;?></h1>

<?php
    if ($hay_errores and $mostrar_form) { echo "<pre>";print_r($errores);echo"</pre>"; }

    if (!$hay_errores and !$mostrar_form) { // presupuesto guardado/actualizado correctamente
        echo "<p class=\"exito\">" . $errores[0] . "</p>";
    }
    if ($mostrar_form) {
        ob_start();
        include 'presupuestos_formulario.php';
//      ob_get_clean();
        ob_end_flush();
    }
include("inc/html_foot.php");
```

Comment: Prueba con `print_r($errores, true);`

Comment: Nope.Nada. El proceso se completa correctamente si no hay errores pero sigue sin mostrar los mensajes de error (cuando debería).

Comment: @masterguru Correcto. Y así funciona. Ahora, si hay errores, vuelve al formulario. Sin mostrar los mensajes de error. Y nada tienen que ver los mensajes de error con el `ob()`

Comment: Lo siento, no te entiendo. En la pregunta dices que cuando no usas el buffer se muestran los mensajes de error, y en este último comentario dices que no tienen nada que ver.

Comment: He reproducido mínimamente tu escenario y a mi me funciona como esta programado tanto si pongo ambas variables ($hay_errores y $mostrar_form) como true como si las pongo como false, con y sin el ob_start().  Eso de que vuelve al formulario cuando hay errores sin mostrar los mensajes de error no lo hace, al menos con el código de tu pregunta que has puesto. No se si es un problema de lógica o de los valores que rellenas en las variables en los scripts que no vemos.

Comment: No interfiere por lo que he podido constatar en mis pruebas. Me inclino más a pensar que hay fallos de lógica o de como generas los valores de esas dos variables.  A menos que el problema esté en el código que no vemos, claro, allí no se si usas de nuevo ob_start() o ob_end_flush() anidados o se hace un lio con eso.